# How to get a reaction from a single message, and not any message with the same emojii

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to assign a role to a member once they react to a message (more specifically once agreeing to rules)

What I currently have works fine:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
                                                                                                    
    cid = client.get_guild(#################) # need this to fetch roles
    channel = client.get_channel(#################)


    role = discord.utils.get(cid.roles, name="member") #fetch server roles

    message = await channel.send("React if you agree, and gain access to the server")
    await message.add_reaction('☑️') # add message and reaction

    reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda reaction, user: reaction.emoji == '☑️') # check for reaction
    await user.add_roles(role)  # assign role when reacted
```

The problem is that, you can react with the emoji on any message and it will still give you the role.

How can I make it so that only that message counts. And no other?

I was hoping for maybe something like `message.wait_for()` (which doesn't seem to exist)

I would think I could fetch the id of the message then somehow compare that to the id of the message the reaction is attached to and compare that. But I have no idea how that could be done.

`user` and `reaction` don't seem to return anything of use

Comment: "I would think I could fetch the id of the message... user and reaction don't seem to return anything of use" Did you try reading [the documentation for the Reaction class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#reaction)? Because when I do that, I see a very interesting-looking `message` attribute.

Comment: Alternately, you could have found the [documentation for `on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) which explicitly gives you the relevant advice; I found that when I tried putting `discord.py react to message` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=discord.py+react+to+message), along with other relevant discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a check function to verify that the reaction was added to the correct message.

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    return reaction.message.id == message.id and str(reaction.emoji) == '☑️'

reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check) # check for reaction
```

---

### Sources

- [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#discord.Client.wait_for)